# Product Design Scaling Issue

Tags: mechanical-engineering, product-engineering

If I want to scale up the product I am designing can I simply double all of my dimensions or is there a better way of going about it?

For context. I was given a finished product and told that it was too small. They asked me to make it twice the size, CAD it and create a drawing.

Comment: Would multiplying by 3 be better? It's not clear what you are asking. Can you edit your question to improve it?

Comment: physical properties are not linear with large scale changes due to 2nd order effects. Define your test criteria and margins to environmental stress after you show what you want

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not that simple.

Are there clearances or running tolerances? If there are then they have to be adjusted.

Imagine a shaft of 15mm in a hole of 18mm, that is a gap of 3mm (1.5mm per side.

Now multiply by 3 ( 3 or 4 or 2 as you wish - just an example), then 15x3=45mm and 18x3=54. Now the difference is 9mm, ie 4.5mm per side. This may be too much and the hole may need reducing or the shaft increasing to bring the gap back to 3mm.